# Inconsistent __name__ when importing packages in Python (Django)

Tags: python, django, import, python-import

I have a Django project with the following structure

```
project/
    package1/
        __init__.py
        api.py
        views.py
    package2/
        __init__.py
        api.py
        views.py
    __init__.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
```

In `package1/api.py` I perform the following import:

`from .views import my_func`

When I do this, the `__name__` value in my `package1/views.py` module is `project.package1.views`, this is exactly what I want.

However when I do the same thing in `package2/api.py`:

`from .views import my_func2`

I get `package2.views` for `__name__`, it's missing the `project` prefix.

I can fix this by using the full `from project.package2.views` path, but I don't understand why it would work for one package but not another.

I don't have anything at all in my `__init__` files that would alter how the `imports` work, either.

Comment: What are you using the `__name__` for?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm setting up loggers with `logging.getLogger(__name__)`.  When I get the abbreviated path it sets up a whole new logger.

However I believe the implications reach further than that.  The `__name__` seems to be how `sys.modules` registers each module.  So if I sometimes get the full path and sometimes get an abbreviated one then I believe `sys.modules` will import two instances of the same module under different names.